# NGINX as load balancer with tomcat6 gives bad gateway error only only HTTPS mode

Tags: nginx, tomcat, load-balancing, tomcat6

I am using nginx as load balancer on tomcat6 webserver. Both NGINX and TOMCAT6 have been configured to use **only HTTPS**. NGINX configuration settings are mentioned in the following two files.

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and the sites-available/default is as follows

```
upstream backend {
server 10.1.2.4;
}

server {


#HTTPS_ENABLED
    listen   443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate        %SSL_CERT%;
    ssl_certificate_key    %SSL_KEY%;
    ssl_ciphers            ALL:!ADH:!kEDH:!SSLv2:!EXPORT40:!EXP:!LOW;
    ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout    10m;
#HTTPS_ENABLED


    location / {
       proxy_pass https://backend;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

If I directly connect the webserver using https link, I am able to access the web application

1) tomcat is up and running and is listening on 443

2) Nothing suspicious on access logs

but If I use the nginx url (https), it is giving me "502 bad gateway" error. I couldn't find any errors or suspicious warning in both access.log and error.log of the nginx.
What could possibly be wrong here? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
upstream backend {
   server 10.1.2.4:443;
}
```

**Edit:** Just to be complete, I think this is also another solution:

```
upstream backend {
   server 10.1.2.4 ssl;
}
```